# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when passing NSString to method from within a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nsstring, objective-c-blocks

I have a method which requests access to Twitter, and then sets the username using `- (void) setUsername:(NSString *)username`. I have to pass `ACAccountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType...` a completion handler (block) as follows:

```
[self.accounts requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAccountType options:NULL completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *actualError) {
    if(granted == YES) {
        self.haveTwitterAccess = YES;
        ACAccount *account = [self.accounts accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType][0];
        [self setUsername: account.username];

// [...]
```

When I do this, however, I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in the `setUsername` method (to which I'm trying to pass `account.username`). If I try `NSLog(@"%@", account.username);` then I can see that the value is correct, but when passed to `setUsername`, the `username` variable is `nil`.

I imagine that it is being released in between the threads somewhere here, but am not sure, what with all this new ARC stuff, how to stop it happening. In essence, this boils down to passing strings between threads I suppose?

I've tried things like `[account.username copy]` and setting the accounts store as `retain` etc., but nothing seems to work. I've also tried referencing `self` using:

```
__block UserManager *blockSafeSelf = self;
```

How to I ensure that the variable passed from within a callback block to a method on another object is retained?

#### EDIT:

This is in a class called `UserManager` which has a property

```
@property (nonatomic) ACAccountStore *accounts;
```

which deals with the Twitter access. It also has the method:

```
- (void) setUsername: (NSString *) username;
```

which I'm trying to call with the account username inside the completion block. I hope that helps pinpoint the issue a bit better.

#### EDIT (2):

`username` is a property of `UserManager` and is declared as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *username;
```

Comment: You say that the username variable is nil but what about `self.username`?  (I'm speculating that maybe the variable with that name isn't the backing variable for the property.)

Comment: Sorry, when I say `username` is `nil`, I mean that a `nil` value is passed to the `setUsername` method.

Comment: What class is self, what about self.accounts.  Please show your declarations.

Comment: @danh updated the post with some more info if that helps?

Comment: One more thing, can you show how you declare username?  Have you tried just setting [self setUsername:@"test"]; without any ACAccounts code?  does that work?

Comment: @danh updated my post. Weirdly I tried just using `[self setUsername: @"my_handle"]` and I got an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. I don't really understand why at this stage. Maybe the `setUsername` declaration is clashing with the synthesised declaration?

Comment: Ok so I changed the method name to `syncUsername` and it works.

Comment: So it seems your problem is unrelated to accounts, and has to do with that property.  Its odd that you've declared the setter at all.  Why not just self.username = @"a string";  Please post the method body of syncUsername.

Comment: I basically had to do some saving with `NSUserDefaults` so I put that stuff in the setter to make sure they're always in sync. I should be able to override the setter without weird (and cryptic) errors being thrown.

Comment: "I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the setUsername method" You get a crash *inside* the `setUsername:` method (which you haven't shown us)? or you get a crash on the line that calls it?

Comment: Can you run this with zombies on to detect any potential use of deallocated objects?

Comment: Sorry, yes - inside the `setUsername:` method, but I've discovered what the problem was (or at least, what the fix was) as mentioned above.